# Assign value to multiple slices in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, slice

In Matlab, you can assign a value to multiple slices of the same list:

```
>> a = 1:10

a =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

>> a([1:3,7:9]) = 10

a =

    10    10    10     4     5     6    10    10    10    10
```

How can you do this in Python with a numpy array?

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)

>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

>>> a[1:3,7:9] = 10
IndexError: too many indices
```

Comment: Any reason why you might want to do it in one statement instead of doing it in two statements?

Comment: @SukritKalra I cannot speak for the question author, but an example case is when one is trying to form a list comprehension from such a multislice (which is what I am trying to do and why I arrived at this question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a = np.arange(10)
a[[range(3)+range(6,9)]] = 10
#or a[[0,1,2,6,7,8]] = 10 

print a
```

that should work I think ... I dont know that its quite what you want though

Comment: Can this be achieved without NumPy?

Comment: Indeed. NumPy is the real King Of The One-Liners.

Answer (score 17):

You might also consider using `np.r_`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html

```
ii = np.r_[0:3,7:10]
a[ii] = 10

In [11]: a
Out[11]: array([ 10, 10, 10,  3,  4,  5,  6, 10, 10,  10])
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html (Section "Index Arrays"). Note that indices for desired slices should be contained within 'np.array()'.

```
>>> x = np.arange(10,1,-1)
>>> x
array([10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2])

>>> x[np.array([3, 3, 1, 8])]
array([7, 7, 9, 2])
```