# Select from multiple slices in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Say we have

```
a = np.ones((3,3,3))
```

and

```
slices = [(0, 1, slice(None)), (0, slice(None), 0),  (slice(None), 1, 0)]
```

Is there a simple way to select/change values of `a` from `slices`?

For example, I want to assign `0` to `a` under slices such that `a` becomes

```
array([[[0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

An iterative way is to do

```
for t in slices:
    a[t] = 0
```

Is there a better way to make use of the indices like `np.r_` like what's used by JoshAdel in [Assign value to multiple slices in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282941/assign-value-to-multiple-slices-in-numpy/16283049#16283049)?

I am hoping to achieve something like `a[SLICES] = 0` and change all part of `a` from each slice in `slices` to `0`.

Comment: that is already very simple and appropriate, isn't it?

Comment: @Rockbar that is true. I am just wondering whether there are alternatives like `np.r`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know what `r_` does?  It converts the slices into ranges, and then concatenates the whole mess together.

I don't know if you can use `r_` or something similar to construct the required indices.  But:

```
In [168]: idx = np.where(a==0)
In [169]: idx
Out[169]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]),
 array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]))
```

this is gives us an idea of the required indexing arrays (minus some likely duplicates).

---

It might be possible to concatenate these 3 `ogrid` lists into a composite:

```
In [181]: np.ogrid[0:1,1:2,:3]
Out[181]: [array([[[0]]]), array([[[1]]]), array([[[0, 1, 2]]])]

In [182]: np.ogrid[0:1,:3,0:1]
Out[182]: 
[array([[[0]]]), array([[[0],
         [1],
         [2]]]), array([[[0]]])]

In [183]: np.ogrid[:3,1:2,0:1]
Out[183]: 
[array([[[0]],

        [[1]],

        [[2]]]), array([[[1]]]), array([[[0]]])]
```

Individually they select the 0s in `a`.

It may be easiest to convert them into their raveled equivalents, and join the resulting 1d arrays.

```
In [188]: np.ravel_multi_index(Out[181],(3,3,3))
Out[188]: array([[[3, 4, 5]]])
etc
In [195]: np.hstack([Out[188].ravel(), Out[189].ravel(), Out[190].ravel()])
Out[195]: array([ 3,  4,  5,  0,  3,  6,  3, 12, 21])
In [197]: a.flat[_]
Out[197]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

In [199]: np.unravel_index(Out[195],(3,3,3))
Out[199]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]),
 array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
```

`Out[169]` and `Out[199]` have the same values, except for duplicates.

This is a generalization of the problem of joining several 1d slices.  Indexing and then concatenating takes about as much time as concatenating the indices first.

Comment: I think you may be right that there is no direct way to achieve things like `np.r_`. These analyses and trial with `np.ogrid` are solid.