# Numpy Dynamic Indexing With Both Slicing and Advanced Indexing

Tags: python, numpy

Looking to index a (N, M) array by taking a certain rows (indicated by an array of row index values) and take a slice from the columns with a fixed start and varying stop indices.

```
population = np.full((N,M), 0) #population of N guys with genome length M
#Choose some guys and change parts of their genome (cols)

rows_indices = [0,1,5,6] #four guys 0,1,5,6 will be changed

#all selected guys will have a start of 10
#the ends will be difference for each guy

slice_lengths = np.random.geometric(p=0.8, size = 4) #vector of 4
```

What I imagine is something like:

```
population[0, 10: 10+ slice_length[0]] = 100
population[1, 10: 10+ slice_length[1]] = 100
population[2, 10: 10+ slice_length[2]] = 100
population[3, 10: 10+ slice_length[3]] = 100
```

Except vectorized without hardcoding each value

```
#false code
population[rows_indices, start: start + slice_length]
```

Comment: If the `slice_length` was consistent, and the `start` varied, it is possible to reform the result into an array, but with some sort of concatenate before or after indexing.  But with variable `slice_length` you are stuck with slicing each row separately.

Comment: @hpaulj is correct, especially because this will cause the rows to become jagged meaning that you will need an array of arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj if you don't mind how would a variable start and a fixed slice_length work?

Comment: take a look at, [Select from multiple slices in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976523/select-from-multiple-slices-in-numpy)